# Python range counter resets at 999 and attaches thousandth number at the end of each string

Tags: python, range, counter

I did a couple searches but did not find a relevant post.

I. What happened:

- I have a list of ~9000 strings [string1, string2, ... string 9001]
- I used a for loop to write each string on its own line with index number:

  ```
  #z is a list with ~9000 items

  y = open('4.3 data.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
  for i in range(0, len(z)):
      y.write(str(i) + '^')
      y.write(str(z[i]))
      y.write('\n')
  y.close()
  ```
- what I get is like the following:

  ```
  0 blahblahblah
  1 blahblahblah
  ...
  998 blahblahblah
  999 blahblahblah
  000 blahblahblah1
  001 blahblahblah1
  ...
  999 blahblahblah1
  000 blahblahblah2
  001 blahblahblah2
  ```
- So, basically it seems like (and I've generally read that) using "range" to count goes up to 999, then it (1) resets at 000 and (2) appends the thousand digit at the end of the string.

II. What I want:

- I'd like to know if there is any way to disable the reset at 1000, 2000, etc. so that I can use range and still have the counter go up to 1000, 2000, 3000, etc.
- If this is not possible/undesirable, I'd like to know what alternative way of iterating over the # of items in a list so that (1) the index doesn't reset (this is not THAT important although it'd be nice) and (2) the string is not modified to have the thousand digit appended at the end of it (I want this a LOT)

Thank you!

Comment: `range` does not automatically reset when it hits 1000. Something else is going on that you haven't shown us.

Comment: You are right - I did a quick test with just a list of numbers and range went over 1000. Something else is going on that I haven't shown, and it's because I misled myself into thinking this. I'll have to look into this more. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more "Pythonic" way of handling this is with [enumeration](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#enumerate).

I would also recommend implementing file I/O by using `open()` as a context manager.

For example:

```
with open('4.3 data.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as y_file:
    for i, item in enumerate(z):
        print(str(i) + ' ' + str(item), file=y_file)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion robinsax! I realized that I misled myself in presenting this question as I commented on user2357112's post - range doesn't always reset at 1000. Maybe it had to do with my working with strings. In any case, I will try out your suggestion and will comment back whether it solved my issue.

Comment: Your method worked flawlessly for me! It (1) made it so that the index went over 999 (2169, etc.) and (2) made it so that the thousand-digit is not appended to the written string. Thank you so much!

Comment: glad to hear it :D